# Amazon Redshift query to get delinquent amount and days past due at the end of month

Tags: mysql, sql, amazon-redshift

Changing the question because of a misunderstanding in use case.

Amazon Redshift Query for the  following problem statement.

The data structure:

1. id - primary key
2. acc_id - id unique to a loan account (this id will be same for all
           emi's for a particular loan account, this maybe repeated 6 times or
           12 times based on loan tenure which can be 6 months or 12 months
           respectively)
3. status - PAID or UNPAID (the emi's unpaid are followed my unpaid
       emi's only)
4. s_id - just a scheduling id which would be consecutive numbers for a
       a particular loan id
5. due_date - the due date for that particular emi
6. principal - amount that is due

The table:

```
   id       acc_id status   s_id    due_date            principal
9999957     10003   PAID    102  2018-07-02 12:00:00        4205
9999958     10003   UNPAID  103  2018-08-02 12:00:00        4100
9999959     10003   UNPAID  104  2018-09-02 12:00:00        4266
9999960     10003   UNPAID  105  2018-10-02 12:00:00        4286
9999962     10004   PAID    106  2018-07-02 12:00:00        3200
9999963     10004   PAID    107  2018-08-02 12:00:00        3100
9999964     10004   UNPAID  108  2018-09-02 12:00:00        3266
9999965     10004   UNPAID  109  2018-10-02 12:00:00        3286
```

The use case -

The unpaid amount becomes delinquent (overdue) after the due_date.

So I need to calculate delinquent amount **at the end of every month** from the first due_date in this case is 2nd July to last due_date (assume it to be 2nd November which is the current month)

I also need to calculate days past due at the end of that month.

Illustration from the above data:

- From the sample data provided, no EMI is due at the end of July so amount delinquent is 0
- But at the end of August - the id 9999958 is due - as of 31st August
  the amount delinquent is 4100 and days past due is 29 (31st August minus 2nd August)

The catch: I need to calculate this for the loan (acc_id) and not the emi.

To further explain, A first EMI will be 29 days due on 1st month and 59 days due on second month, also second EMI will be 29 days due on second month. **But I need this at loan level (acc_id).**

The same example continued for 30th september, the acc_id 10003 is due since 2nd August so as of 30th September the due amount is 8366 (4100 + 4266) and DPD (days_past_due) is 59 (29 + 30).

Also acc_id 10004 is due 3100 and DPD is 28 (30th september - 2nd september).

The final output would be something like this:

```
Month_End   DPD_Band    Amount
2018/08/31  0-29        4100
2018/08/31  30-59       0
2018/08/31  60-89       0
2018/08/31  90+         0
2018/09/30  0-29        3100
2018/09/30  30-59       8366
2018/09/30  60-89       0
2018/09/30  90+         0
```

Query attempt: DPD bands can be created based on case statements on delinquent days. I need real help in first creating End-of-months and then finding the portfolio level amounts as explained above for different delinquent days.

Comment: I have removed all those conflicting dbms tags. Put one of them back, the one for the dbms actually used.

Comment: Specify the expected result as well - as formatted text. And show us your current query attempt.

Comment: Okay, new here. Thanks for noticing.

Comment: why mysql tag? is this mysql or redshift?

Comment: The data is avialble on both mysql and Redshift.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited to be RedShift compatible after the op clarified which RDBMS.  *(MySQL would need a different answer)*

The following creates one record for each month between your first record, and the end of last month.

It then joins on to your unpaid records, and the aggregation chooses which bracket to put the results in to.

```
WITH
  first_month AS
(
  SELECT LAST_DAY(MIN(due_date)) AS end_date FROM yourTable
),
  months AS
(
  SELECT
    LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(first_month.end_date, s.id))    AS end_date
  FROM
    first_month
  CROSS JOIN
    generate_series(
      1,
      DATEDIFF(month, (SELECT end_date FROM first_month), CURRENT_DATE)
    )
      AS s(id)
),
  monthly_delinquents AS
(
  SELECT
    yourTable.*,
    months.end_date                                        AS month_end_date,
    DATEDIFF(DAY, yourTable.due_date, months.end_date)     AS days_past_due
  FROM
    months
  LEFT JOIN
    yourTable
      ON  yourTable.status   = 'UNPAID'
      AND yourTable.due_date < months.end_date
)
SELECT
  month_end_date,
  SUM(CASE WHEN days_past_due >= 00 AND days_past_due < 30 THEN principal ELSE 0 END)  AS dpd_00_29,
  SUM(CASE WHEN days_past_due >= 30 AND days_past_due < 60 THEN principal ELSE 0 END)  AS dpd_30_59,
  SUM(CASE WHEN days_past_due >= 60 AND days_past_due < 90 THEN principal ELSE 0 END)  AS dpd_60_89,
  SUM(CASE WHEN days_past_due >= 90                        THEN principal ELSE 0 END)  AS dpd_90plus
FROM
  monthly_delinquents
GROUP BY
  month_end_date
ORDER BY
  month_end_date
```

That said, normally the idea of pivoting things like this is a bad idea.  What happens when something is a year past due?  It just sits in the 90plus category and never moves.  And, if you want to expand it you need to change the query and any other query you ever write that depends on it.

Instead, you could normalise your output...

```
WITH
  first_month AS
(
  SELECT LAST_DAY(MIN(due_date)) AS end_date FROM yourTable
),
  months AS
(
  SELECT
    LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(first_month.end_date, s.id))    AS end_date
  FROM
    first_month
  CROSS JOIN
    generate_series(
      1,
      DATEDIFF(month, (SELECT end_date FROM first_month), CURRENT_DATE)
    )
      AS s(id)
),
  monthly_delinquents AS
(
  SELECT
    yourTable.*,
    months.end_date                                        AS month_end_date,
    DATEDIFF(DAY, yourTable.due_date, months.end_date)     AS days_past_due
  FROM
    months
  LEFT JOIN
    yourTable
      ON  yourTable.status   = 'UNPAID'
      AND yourTable.due_date < months.end_date
)
SELECT
  month_end_date,
  (days_past_due / 30) * 30   AS days_past_due_band,
  SUM(principal)              AS total_principal,
  COUNT(*)                    AS total_rows
FROM
  monthly_delinquents
GROUP BY
  month_end_date,
  (days_past_due / 30) * 30
ORDER BY
  month_end_date,
  (days_past_due / 30) * 30
```

Comment: This is perfect Mat. But can you see my updated use case. The only thing additional on this is instead of individual emi, the sum(principal) should be for all unpaid loans before the date for that particular user.

Comment: and dpd should be calculated from the first unpaid loan

Comment: Hey Mat, can you help me with the updated use case? I can provide more understanding, im really struggling with it

Comment: Do you want me to create another question?